# How do I put media:thumbnail in RSS feed

Tags: php, xml

I can't get the thumbnail images to display in the RSS feed items. Where do I put the code for the image to so up?

first tried the getElementsByTagName but of course that doesn't work, then I tried your solution- $item_img = $item->getElementsByTagNameNS('the namespace URI you found','thumbnail')
                 ->item(0)->getAttribute('url'); 
But that brought back an error that broke the whole page. I think I understand that thumbnail is a sub element of media: and I see that it is part of jwplayer:feedid under media:group. So, does it go in the array like the other items? I tried it inside the array and outside as well. Where do I put it to display the thumbnail in my newsfeed item?

```
<?php
$rss = new DOMDocument();
$rss->load('https://cdn.jwplayer.com/v2/playlists/IYxiCISJ?format=mrss');
$feed = array();
foreach ($rss->getElementsByTagName('item') as $node) {
    $item = array ( 
        'title' => $node->getElementsByTagName('title')->item(0)->nodeValue,
        'desc' => $node->getElementsByTagName('description')->item(0)->nodeValue,
        'link' => $node->getElementsByTagName('link')->item(0)->nodeValue,
        'date' => $node->getElementsByTagName('pubDate')->item(0)->nodeValue,

        );

    array_push($feed, $item);
}
$limit = 5;
for($x=0;$x<$limit;$x++) {
    $title = str_replace(' & ', ' &amp; ', $feed[$x]['title']);
    $link = $feed[$x]['link'];
    $description = $feed[$x]['desc'];
    $date = date('l F d, Y', strtotime($feed[$x]['date']));
    echo '<p><strong><a href="'.$link.'" title="'.$title.'">'.$title.'</a></strong><br />';
    echo '<small><em>Posted on '.$date.'</em></small></p>';
    echo '<p>'.$description.'</p>';
}
```

Here is the xml file output I am trying to parse:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<rss version="2.0" xmlns:media="http://search.yahoo.com/mrss/" xmlns:jwplayer="http://rss.jwpcdn.com/">
<channel>
  <title>Car Repairs</title>
  <description>Car Repairs</description>
  <jwplayer:kind>MANUAL</jwplayer:kind>
  <jwplayer:feedid>IYxiCISJ</jwplayer:feedid>
  <jwplayer:feed_instance_id>7beba58b-b2a2-4000-af11-1e43a7cb8680</jwplayer:feed_instance_id>
  <jwplayer:link rel="first" href="https://cdn.jwplayer.com/v2/playlists/IYxiCISJ?format=mrss&amp;page_offset=1&amp;page_limit=500"/>
  <jwplayer:link rel="last" href="https://cdn.jwplayer.com/v2/playlists/IYxiCISJ?format=mrss&amp;page_offset=1&amp;page_limit=500"/>
  <item>
    <title>Preparing the Audi A8 for Service- The American Garage</title>
    <link>https://cdn.jwplayer.com/previews/ybcuKyZl</link>
    <description>Putting Audi A8 in service mode.</description>
    <pubDate>Mon, 17 Sep 2018 14:35:11 -0000</pubDate>
    <guid isPermaLink="false">ybcuKyZl</guid>
    <enclosure url="https://cdn.jwplayer.com/videos/ybcuKyZl-qQFQ3TOZ.mp4" type="video/mp4" length="515"/>
    <jwplayer:feedid>IYxiCISJ</jwplayer:feedid>
      <media:group>
      <media:content url="https://cdn.jwplayer.com/manifests/ybcuKyZl.m3u8" medium="video" type="application/vnd.apple.mpegurl" duration="515"/>
      <media:content url="https://cdn.jwplayer.com/videos/ybcuKyZl-jTncGIBU.mp4" medium="video" type="video/mp4" duration="515" width="320" height="180" fileSize="19714361"/>
      <media:content url="https://cdn.jwplayer.com/videos/ybcuKyZl-i4o7KXqD.mp4" medium="video" type="video/mp4" duration="515" width="480" height="270" fileSize="29378682"/>
      <media:content url="https://cdn.jwplayer.com/videos/ybcuKyZl-XMc5nvLA.mp4" medium="video" type="video/mp4" duration="515" width="720" height="406" fileSize="40249178"/>
      <media:content url="https://cdn.jwplayer.com/videos/ybcuKyZl-qQFQ3TOZ.mp4" medium="video" type="video/mp4" duration="515" width="1280" height="720" fileSize="109187664"/>
      <media:content url="https://cdn.jwplayer.com/videos/ybcuKyZl-MTvbpSOY.m4a" medium="video" type="audio/mp4" duration="515" fileSize="7304077"/>
      <media:thumbnail url="https://cdn.jwplayer.com/thumbs/ybcuKyZl-720.jpg" width="720" />
      <media:keywords>The American Garage,thermostat,timing belt audi,audi a8,audi 4.2,water pump,service mode,A8,audi,car repairs</media:keywords>
    </media:group>
    <jwplayer:track file="https://cdn.jwplayer.com/strips/ybcuKyZl-120.vtt" kind="thumbnails"/>
  </item>
</channel>
</rss>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All that's needed is to pass the correct namespace URI to [`DOMDocument::getElementsByTagNameNS()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/domdocument.getelementsbytagnamens.php). (Rather than hard-coding it you can get the attribute from the XML document if you think it will change.)

In addition, you can't escape data for HTML just by replacing `&` with `&amp;` there are [built-in functions](http://php.net/htmlspecialchars) for that purpose, use them for all your data.

```
<?php
$rss = new DOMDocument();
$rss->load('https://cdn.jwplayer.com/v2/playlists/IYxiCISJ?format=mrss');
// get the namespace URI
$mediaURL = $rss->documentElement->getAttribute("xmlns:media");
foreach ($rss->getElementsByTagName('item') as $node) {
    $feed[] = [
        'title' => $node->getElementsByTagName('title')->item(0)->nodeValue,
        'desc' => $node->getElementsByTagName('description')->item(0)->nodeValue,
        'link' => $node->getElementsByTagName('link')->item(0)->nodeValue,
        'date' => $node->getElementsByTagName('pubDate')->item(0)->nodeValue,
        // get the namespaced element value
        'thumbnail' => $node->getElementsByTagNameNS($mediaURL, 'thumbnail')->item(0)->getAttribute('url'),
    ];
}

foreach ($feed as $item) {
    $title = htmlspecialchars($item["title"]);
    $link = htmlspecialchars($item["link"]);
    $description = htmlspecialchars($item["desc"]);
    $date = htmlspecialchars(date('l F d, Y', strtotime($item['date'])));
    $thumbnail = htmlspecialchars($item["thumbnail"]);
    echo <<< HTML

<p>
    <a href="$link" title="$title">
        <img src="$thumbnail" alt="$title"/>
        <br/>
        <strong>$title</strong>
    </a>
    <small><em>Posted on $date</em></small>
</p>
<p>
    $description
</p>

HTML;
}
```

Comment: Thank you @Miken32, that worked out very well. I am not so good with PHP yet.  Using the echo to give a place to put in the html seems a lot cleaner than to echo every line. Now I can use whatever html I want to stylize it. I used the & with &amp; because that was what I was shown before. One other question- I tried to remove the $limit line to show all available records, but it broke the page. I set a limit above the number of records, but it shows extra blank records to fill the list to that number. Is there an easy was to make the limit  equal the number of existing records?

Comment: Why are you reading the media-rss namespace URI from the document? Unlike the alias/prefix it is not a value that could change.

Comment: Version changes can result in different namespace URIs.

Comment: @StephenDevine code is updated with a simple `foreach` loop.

Comment: @miken32 you are awesome! I was just starting to understand how to change it, and you updated the code ! Thank you for this Christmas present! Here is how the page has turned out so far- http://www.theamericangarage.us/watch-videos/car-repair

Comment: No problem @StephenDevine. If this has answered your question, mark it accepted with the check mark.

Comment: @miken32 would you contact me, I have a couple other functions I would like to implement that are more sophisticated than my skills.